# How to remove all images from a worksheet using PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

As by the title, I'm using PHPExcel to transform excel files in pdf parts. Extractions rows from sheets. I'd like to remove all the images from a given sheets. Is there a method ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This the working code:

```
$drawingCollection = $workBook->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection();
foreach ($drawingCollection as $key => $drawing) {
    $drawingCollection->offsetUnset($key);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the images by exchanging the images with an empty array

```
/** @var ArrayObject $drawingItems */
$drawingItems = $phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection();
$drawingItems->exchangeArray(array());
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious approach would be to retrieve the image collection for the worksheet using the worksheet's `getDrawingCollection()` method. This returns an ArrayObject, and you should be able to [unset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.offsetunset.php) each element in turn.

Comment: Thanks, but I miss something... :

    $drawingCollection =$workBook->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection();
    foreach ($drawingCollection as $drawing) unset($drawing);
    $drawingCollection->setWorksheet($workBook->getActiveSheet());

got en error... is there a setDrawingCollection ?

Comment: No, and there shouldn't need to be; you're modifying $drawingCollection which is an __ArrayObject__ (an object, not a standard PHP array), so you're accessing it effectively "by reference".... use the `ArrayObject::offsetUnset()` method that I linked in my answer